# how to upload a video around 200 mb from cordova /angular mobile application

Tags: angular, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I have a mobile application developed using cordova / angular/ ionic1. Now I need to upload videos to a server from that mobile app.

could upload small videos (around 20 mb) using $cordovaFileTransfer plugin.
But I need to find a way to upload atleast 200 mb.

Thanks in advance, for your help on this issue !

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely you need to check server config. Look for a max post size, max upload size and possibly time limits.

Comment: Thanks for your response. has done these changes in web.config file which has the uploading function. I use MVC Controller to upload file. going to upload files to a azure blob storage account            <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="5000"></sessionState>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="10240000" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <httpModules>

Comment: is there any other places to change limits or sizes?